# MapBox - detect zoomLevel changes

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

How can I simply detect zoom level changes? Is it possible?

I simply need to hide my annotation views when zoom level is not enough.

`regionDidChange:animated:` is not intended to use for me. Any other way?

I need to hide my labels here:

[image]

and show them here:

[image]

This is what I currently do with my labels:

```
class CardAnnotation: MGLPointAnnotation {

    var card: Card

    init(card: Card) {
        self.card = card
        super.init()

        let coordinates = card.border.map { $0.coordinate }
        let sumLatitudes = coordinates.map { $0.latitude }.reduce(0, +)
        let sumLongitudes = coordinates.map { $0.longitude }.reduce(0, +)
        let averageLatitude = sumLatitudes / Double(coordinates.count)
        let averageLongitude = sumLongitudes / Double(coordinates.count)

        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: averageLatitude, longitude: averageLongitude)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

```
var annotations = [CardAnnotation]()
mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `regionDidChange:animated:` doesn't work for your use case?

Comment: Because within that function I remove annotations and add and show all of them again. it lags...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of the two main [ways to add overlays](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.0.0/adding-markers-to-a-map.html) to an `MGLMapView`, the runtime styling API is better suited for text labels and also for varying the appearance based on the zoom level. While you’re at it, you might as well create the polygons using the same API too.

Start by creating polygon features for the areas you want shaded in:

```
var cards: [MGLPolygonFeature] = []
var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = […]
let card = MGLPolygonFeature(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
card.attributes = ["address": 123]
// …
cards.append(card)
```

Within any method that runs after the map finishes loading, such as `MGLMapViewDelegate.mapView(_:didFinishLoading:)`, add a shape source containing these features to the current style:

```
let cardSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "cards", features: cards, options: [:])
mapView.style?.addSource(cardSource)
```

With the shape source in place, create a style layer that renders the polygon features as mauve fills:

```
let fillLayer = MGLFillStyleLayer(identifier: "card-fills", source: cardSource)
fillLayer.fillColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9098039216, green: 0.8235294118, blue: 0.9647058824, alpha: 1))
mapView.style?.addLayer(fillLayer)
```

Then create another style layer that renders labels at each polygon feature’s centroid. (`MGLSymbolStyleLayer` automatically calculates the centroids, accounting for irregularly shaped polygons.)

```
// Same source as the fillLayer.
let labelLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "card-labels", source: cardSource)
// Each feature’s address is an integer, but text has to be a string.
labelLayer.text = NSExpression(format: "CAST(address, 'NSString')")
// Smoothly interpolate from transparent at z16 to opaque at z17.
labelLayer.textOpacity = NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'linear', nil, %@)",
                                      [16: 0, 17: 1])
mapView.style?.addLayer(labelLayer)
```

As you customize these style layers, pay particular attention to the options on `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` that control whether nearby symbols are automatically hidden due to collision. You may find that the automatic collision detection makes it unnecessary to specify the `textOpacity` property.

---

When you create the source, one of the options you can pass into the `MGLShapeSource` initializer is `MGLShapeSourceOption.clustered`. However, in order to use that option, you’d have to create `MGLPointFeature`s, not `MGLPolygonFeature`s. Fortunately, `MGLPolygonFeature` has a `coordinate` property that lets you find the centroid without manual calculations:

```
var cardCentroids: [MGLPointFeature] = []
var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = […]
let card = MGLPolygonFeature(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
let cardCentroid = MGLPointFeature()
cardCentroid.coordinate = card.coordinate
cardCentroid.attributes = ["address": 123]
cardCentroids.append(cardCentroid)
// …
let cardCentroidSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "card-centroids", features: cardCentroids, options: [.clustered: true])
mapView.style?.addSource(cardCentroidSource)
```

This clustered source can only be used with `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` or `MGLCircleStyleLayer`, not `MGLFillStyleLayer`. [This example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/) shows how to work with clustered points in more detail.

Comment: I will take a look at that later and if everything will work I will award a bounty for you;)

Comment: Your code doesnt work;) `Cannot assign NSExpression to type MGLStyleValue<NSString>!`. What do you think about that? I try to assign text to labelLayer.

Comment: Ah, NSExpression is only supported in v4.0.0 and above. In v3.x, use an identity interpolation function: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.8/using-style-functions-at-runtime.html#identity

Comment: One thing was left for me. How to assign name attribute of every card as a text of `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`?.
 `labelLayer.text = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: "name") //NSExpression(format: "CAST(name, 'NSString')")` doesnt work for now.

Comment: Now I know: `layer.text = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: "{name}")`

Answer (score 3):

One option is to add the labels as a `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`, then determine the `textOpacity` based on zoom level.

If you are using the current version of the Maps SDK for iOS, you could try something like:

`symbols.textOpacity = NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'linear', nil, %@)", [16.9: 0, 17: 1])`

The [dynamically styled interactive points](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/runtime-multiple-annotations/) example shows one approach to this.

Comment: Hi, how exactly can I add my labels using `MGLSymbolStyleLayer`? I just updated the question with my current code. I will award a bounty for you if you help me with this;) Thank you

Comment: `MGLSymbolStyleLayer` is part of the runtime styling API, a lower-level way to add content to the map than annotations. The runtime styling API is well-suited to use cases like yours that involve text. More about it here: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.0.0/adding-markers-to-a-map.html

Comment: Not specifically for what you’re trying to do, so I posted https://stackoverflow.com/a/50483520/4585461 to walk you through the basics. As @jmkiley pointed out, https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/runtime-multiple-annotations/ shows something similar and goes a step further by showing a callout when the user taps on a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that when you zoom out, your annotations are too close together? If so, it is better to group them together than to hide them entirely. See [*Decluttering a Map with MapKit Annotation Clustering*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering).

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: FYI, this question was about the Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS, not MapKit. The Mapbox SDK supports clustering shape sources but not annotations.

Comment: Whoops, these instructions are for MapKit. Please disregard this answer.